# Соединить два файла-образа разделов в один образ диска и сделать его загрузочным

Tags: linux, grub, mbr, fdisk, dd

Хочу создать образ диска в виде файла `img` из двух файлов-образов разделов (также `img`). Затем переконвертировать в его в `vdi` - образ, с которого в VirtualBox загрузить всю систему - этот пункт я знаю как сделать (`VBoxManage convertdd disk.img disk.vdi`).

Чтобы было понятней, напишу так:

Есть диск с рабочей системой, система работает как гостевая под управлением Proxmox:

```
df -h
...
/dev/sdb1       225M  140M   73M  66% /boot
/dev/sdb3        28G   21G  5,2G  81% /
```

Визуально диск выглядит так:

[image: диск]

```
fdisk /dev/sdb: 50.5 GB, 50465865728 bytes, 98566144 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
...
Disk label type: dos
Disk indentifier: 0x2fda227d

   Device   Boot  Start      End         Blocks     Id    System
/dev/sdb1   *     2048       503807      250880     83    Linux
/dev/sdb3         34605056   93143039    29268992   83    Linux
```

Я загрузился с Live-CD и снял два файла-образа через `Create Partition Image` - указал стрелками. Один - загрузочный, там `grub`, на другом - вся остальная система:

- `boot.img` - загрузочный
- `base.img` - система

Теперь я хочу собрать один `img` файл, который переконвертировать в VirtualVox формат `vdi` (это я умею).

[Вот тут](https://superuser.com/a/841582/1009290) я нашел алгоритм действий, но были неудачные эксперименты и появились вопросы.

Я вижу решение проблемы так:

- создать пустой файл `img` через `fallocate -l 40G desc.img`
- через `fdisk` создать два раздела, поставить флаг `bootable` для первого
- подрубить диск через `losetup -f --show desc.img`, запомнить номер устройства `/dev/loopY`
- сделать `kpartx -a /dev/loopY`
- сделать `dd` `boot.img` и `base.img` на соответствующие `/dev/loopYp1` и `/dev/loopYp1`

Боюсь что это не будет работать, так как не до конца понимаю процесс. Также:

- не знаю, нужно ли делать создание MBR `dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/loopY conv=notrunc` и откуда его взять (на исходной системе этого нет, можно ли взять от другой системы и "доработать")? Или в образе `boot.img` уже есть MBR?
- в исходном диске система размещалась по другим секторам, сможет ли `/boot` найти систему?
- как можно диагностировать в чем, проблема, если я вставляю конечный `vdi` в VirtualBox, но он не грузится с сообщением, что нет загрузочного диска. Или просто черный экран?
- если создать загрузочный образ только из `boot.img` (`boot.vdi` => `/dev/sda` в гостевой), а `base.img` подключить как второй диск (`base.vdi` => `/dev/sdb` в гостевой), сможет ли система загрузиться в VirtualBox? Очень долго копировать 30 Гб в экспериментах, хочу исключить этот шаг.

### UPD.

Отвел 40 Гб под будущий образ:

```
fallocate -l 40G dest.img
```

затем:

```
fdisk dest.img
n
p
1
2048
513807 (тут я немного накинул на всякий случай)

n
p
2
514048 (по-умолчанию)
83886079 (по-умолчанию)

p
Устр-во    Загрузочный  Start Конец Секторы   Size Id Тип
dest.img1  *             2048   513807   511760 249,9M 83 Linux
dest.img2              514048 83886079 83372032  39,8G 83 Linux
w
```

Затем

```
losetup -f --show dest.img
# получилось /dev/loop6
kpartx -a /dev/loop6
```

потом скопировал разделы:

```
dd if=boot.img of=/dev/mapper/loop6p1 conv=notrunc
dd if=base.img of=/dev/mapper/loop6p2 conv=notrunc
```

затем попробовал отмонтировать `losetup -d /dev/loop6`, но `losetup -l` все равно показывает `/dev/loop6`.

Потом преобразовал `VBoxManage convertdd dest.img dest.vdi`, и посмотрел через Live CD - диск есть, вроде все норм, но попытка загрузиться с него выдает что `no bootable media...`.

### UPD2.

```
mkdir ./boot
mount /dev/loop6 ./boot
grub-install --recheck --boot-directory=./boot /dev/loop6
# Установка для платформы i386-pc.
# Установка завершена. Ошибок нет.

resize2fs /dev/mapper/loop6p1
# The filesystem on /dev/mapper/loop6p1 is now 63970 (4k) blocks long.

kpartx -r /dev/loop6
# loop6p1 : 0 511760 /dev/loop6 2048
# loop6p2 : 0 83372032 /dev/loop6 514048

losetup --detach /dev/loop6
```

После загрузки система проваливается в загрузчик grub:

```
grub >
```

Что-то я делаю не так...

### UPD3.

Переставлял grub несколько раз, вот основные эксперименты

#### Первая переустановка grub - со своей машинки Ubuntu 16.04

```
losetup --partscan /dev/loop8 ./dest.img
```

затем `grub-install` и остальные действия.

После превращения в образ VBox и загрузки с него пишет, что не найден загрузочный диск `no such device: (guid диска /dev/sda1 - это то что раньше было в boot.img)`.

Загружаюсь с LiveCD, с таким guid диск существует, это то что раньше было в `boot.img` и куда ставился grub. Команда

```
grub rescue > ls
(hd0) # тут выводится только это
```

#### Вторая переустановка grub - внутри VBox

Загрузился с LiveCD внутри VirtualBox (CentOS 7.8). Далее сделал [по инструкции восстановления grub](https://losst.ru/vosstanovlenie-grub2):

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev; mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys; mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

Затем `grub-install --recheck /dev/sda`. Установщик вывел предупреждение, что нет `/dev/sda3` (там раньше была система, теперь это `/dev/sda2`). При перезагрузке выводится экран grub:

```
(Добро пожаловать в Граб версии 0.97 ... нажмите Tab для списка команд)
grub >
```

Понажимая `cd /` + `Tab` я понял, что там каталог `/grub/` и файлы `/initramfs-...`, `vmlinuz-2.6` - то есть `/boot`, а корневой файловой системы нет.

Затем я проделал все это заново, но отредактировал файл `/etc/mtab`, где заменил монтирование корня `/dev/sda3` на `/dev/sda2`, `grub-install` больше не выводил предупреждение.

Система по-прежнему не загружалась. Наконец, я понял в чем дело, и создал конфигурационный файл `/boot/grub/grub.conf`, поместив в него прежднее содержимое, которое ранее удалил в экспериментах (удалял полностью `/grub`).

Система стала загружаться.

Comment: 513807 - накидывал бы 512000 =)

Comment: загрузчик переустанови `grub-install`

Comment: @eri, поставил grub (@see UPD2). Но при загрузке он запускается и предлагает вводить команды: `grub >`. Я что-то сделал не так, или теперь нужно его сконфигрурировать?

Comment: через losetup --partscan и далее как у меня ставь

Comment: @eri, с помощью вашей помощи я продвинулся довольно далеко, и наконец сделал это! спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно место под таблицу разделов, хотя дальше будет seek... но пусть будет:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=512 count=2048
```

Потом добавим разделы без дырки в 17G

```
dd if=boot.img of=disk.img bs=512 seek=2048

#dd if=base.img of=disk.img bs=512 seek=503808
```

Тут по 512 писаться будет довольно долго. Рекомендую сдвинуть 503808 сдвинуть на 512000, тогда можно писать большим блоком

```
dd if=base.img of=disk.img bs=10485760 seek=25
```

А MBR можно пересоздать поверх

```
fdisk disk.img
```

И команды

```
o
n
p
1
2048
511999
a
n
p
2
512000
+29268992
w
```

Вместо +29268992 можно просто энтер. Если там были надписи вроде `Partition #1 contains a ext4 signature.` - это хорошо - значит попали в сектор.

Но тут GRUB не установлен ещё. Может не стартануть.

```
modprobe loop
losetup --partscan /dev/loop1 ./disk.img
```

Если нет опции --partscan, то можно через

```
kpartx -a /dev/loop1
```

Дальше смонтируем бут и запишем на него новый граб

```
mkdir ./boot
mount /dev/loop1p1 ./boot

grub-install --recheck --boot-directory=./boot /dev/loop1
```

Или может повезет и без монтирования, но иногда не срабатывает.

```
grub-install /dev/loop1
```

Поправим размер бута (~40 мегабайт добавилось свободного пространства вместо 17Г)

```
resize2fs /dev/loop1p1
```

Вот и загрузочный образ готов.

Чуток прибраться за собой

```
kpartx -r /dev/loop1
losetup --detach /dev/loop1
```

ПС. Если первый раздел большой, и ддшить его по 512 долго, то

```
cp boot.img disk.img
fallocate --insert-range -o 0  -l 1048576 ./disk.img
```

По вопросам:

- лучше через fdisk
- boot ищет систему по UUID файловой системы - найдет.
- там разные сообщения: диск не загрузочный, нет загрузчика, может загрузиться в граб но не найти бут, может найти бут, но не найти рут
- можно, но монтировать его надо будет как /dev/sdb. Я тут написал как ддшить его побыстрей выше. Можешь намучаться с переписыванием конфига загрузчика, но сделай ка так:

```bsh
fallocate --insert-range -o 0  -l 1048576 ./base.img

fdisk ./base.img

o
n
p
1
#энтер
#энтер
w
```

Так диск будет виден как sdb1 и загрузчк по UUID его найдет

Comment: Спасибо, я только что сделал образ через fdisk и dd, немного по-другому - fallocate, затем рабивка fdisk, затем подмонировал losetup, затем kpartx, затем dd обоих на `/dev/mapper/loop6p1` и `/dev/mapper/loop6p2` - как написано [тут](https://superuser.com/questions/841560/making-a-vdi-image-bootable-for-virtualbox). Но он не стартует, пишет что-то типа "no boot media". Сейчас наверное лучше поправлю вопрос если не возражаете, чтобы понять на каком я этапе

Comment: сделай раздел активным (a в fdisk) и переустанови grub

Comment: через kpartx граб плохо встает, лучше партскан в лосетап. хотя сислинукс залетает на раз.

Comment: уважаемый @eri, посмотрите мой UPD в вопросе - как я понял, я то же самое, но другим путем, но не работает. получается мне нужно переставить grub?