# Можно ли забрать место из диска С и присвоить его Линуксу?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

На одном диске стоят параллельно винда и линукс. Для софта на линуксе не хватает места. Не хочется сносить линукс и переразмечать диск...  Нельзя ли забрать место у винды и отдать линуксу??

Comment: снести и поставить поновой быстрее

Comment: можно. gparted или любой другой разметчик диска (Акронис) и вперед нарезать. Правда после этого может не загрузиться, но это другое дело)

Comment: Самое смешное, что в такой ситуации винда позволяет немного больше, чем линукс. Её базовая функциональность, вроде бы, позволяет без переазбиения добавлять к диску дополнительную область. А вот в линуксе задачу "увеличить размер диска" не получилось решить ни разу

Comment: @S.H. `позволяет без переазбиения добавлять к диску дополнительную область` - интересно это как? Файловая система лежит поверх раздела, раздел - это разметка диска. Без изменения раздела больше места не может стать. `задачу "увеличить размер диска" не получилось решить ни разу` - для этого как минимум, есть [lvm](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LVM). ТС, можете загрузиться с флешки, и переразбить все как вам хочется. Второе, у вас появится свободное место между 1 и 2 раздеом. Его не получится просто так прибить ко второму, так как нужно перемещать данные и обновлять загрузчик. Можно напортачить.

Comment: Я недавно решал [ровно такую задачу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1126972/287469). Причем у меня разделы были в виде файлов, и был простор для экспериментов. Проще снести что-то одно, переразбить, и поставить заново. Хотя... свободное место можно подрубить через LVM

Comment: @TotalPusher - прошу прощения, я имею в виду вот что: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/storage/disk-management/extend-a-basic-volume Я не хотел бы затеватьрелигиозную войну, но 10 лет пользуюсь линуксом, и не могу понять lvm. Хорошо, что у Вас это всё получается. Обычно задача звучит так: есть "юлочное устройство" (файл) диска виртуальной машины, и на нём кончается место. В винде - увеличил файл, потыкал в виртуалке мышкой - и вот тебе увеличенный диск. Линукс: надо знать еще одну абстракцию (lvm) над файловой системой, со своей системой команд и своей логикой

Comment: @S.H. я посмотрел по ссылке, точно так же легко это делается на линуксе. Если `только если пустое пространство не содержит томов (то есть не распределено) и располагается сразу за расширяемым томом без других промежуточных томов`. То есть в случае ТС, в винде не получится сделать все также просто, даже если на втором разделе был не линукс, а вторая винда. Прелесть lvm - не нужно потом исправлять косячную разбивку. И да, чтобы работать с компьютером "на ты", нужны знания. ТС, есть вариант сжать раздел с виндой, а пустое место подрубить в виде lvm туда, где вам нужно.

Comment: Автору вопроса: кажется, совет от  Total Pusher - "сжать раздел с виндой, а пустое место подрубить в виде lvm туда, где вам нужно" - это лучшее, что можно посоветовать.

Comment: 1. Через виндовский менеджер дисков откусываете от диска нужное количество места ("сжать диск"). 2. Под линуксом создаете на свободном месте новый раздел, форматируете в нужный формат (например, ext4). 3. Смотрите по размерам, какой из "больших" каталогов линукса можно поместить на новый раздел (например, какой-нибудь /usr/share или /home, или вообще /usr). 4. Грузите линукс в однорыльный режим, монтируете новый раздел во временный каталог, переносите данные на него, перемонтируете новый раздел в тот каталог, из которого брали данные, прописываете это все в fstab и получаете свободное место.

Comment: вопрос состоит из двух: 1. как сократить размер файловой системы, и затем блочного устройства («раздела»), занимаемого ms/windows. 2. как использовать освободившееся пространство в gnu/linux. // первый из вопросов, если ответ на него не очевиден, стоит задать отдельно, а на второй ответ здесь [уже есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583657/178576). // поэтому я голосую за закрытие данного вопроса как «составного».

Comment: @S.H. `не могу понять lvm` [вот тут в ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547217/178576) я в виде «картинки» изобразил. надеюсь, она как-то поможет в «понимании lvm».